# Can't run SDK Manager because of Java

Tags: java, android, android-sdk-manager

I tried to run SDK Manager , but the only thing I achieved is that command prompt window pops up and then disappears. I tried opening :

> android-SDK-windows/tools/android

in cmd but it said : `No suitable Java found`.When I try to install Java , both online and offline versions, Program Compatibility Assistant tells me that it's already installed , but Java's uninstallation tool and version verification can't find anything . How can I get Java up and running ?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19182-01/820-7851/inst_cli_jdk_javahome_t/

Comment: Do you have Java SDK or Android SDK installed?

Comment: @EduardoRascon I want to install Android SDK but i can't, because JDK doesn't install neither on my windows 7 nor on windows 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try reinstalling windows, and then installing SDK manager one more time.